# Block unwanted change in system time on windows

Tags: windows, group-policy, time

I don't want users to be able to change the system time. For this, I have set the Group Policy "Change the system time" to include only my Administrator account. I want to know the validity of this measure. Is there any way that despite this check, users will be able to change the system time by using some workaround technique that I am unaware of?

Comment: Have you also password protected the BIOS?

Comment: No, I haven't done that. Is there a way to change the system through the BIOS? If so then please direct to me to an informative link.

Comment: Yes, all systems I've seen allow you to set the system time via the BIOS. Even if you lock down Windows, if you leave the BIOS accessible then they can obviously still change the system time.

Answer (score 0):

If they can either:

1. Access the BIOS settings
2. Boot to another operating system (for example from USB stick, CD-drive etc)

Then they can change the system time.

Since you are security conscious, you will have password-protected the bios and locked down the boot drive to only permit the HDD with the operating system on.